# Exception message when using MemoryStream to an Array

Tags: c#, datagridview, bitmap, memorystream

I keep getting an exception message

> Value Cannot Be Null    Parameter name : Encoder

Which seems to be triggered by the line starting

"picture Box3.Image.Save(ms...." etc.

I am using pictureBox3 to hold a cropped bitmap and I want to put that into the DataGridView1 along with some comments and a ref. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I am having these issues. Many thanks Steve

```
private void btnsavenote_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (panel3.BackgroundImage != null)
  {
    try
    {
      //  crop showimagefn.Text at xloc, yloc ,708,530 
      Image croparea = Image.FromFile(showimagefn.Text);
      Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(croparea);
      croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone  (new Rectangle(((-xloc) - (708 / 2)), ((-yloc) - (530 / 2)), 708, 530), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); //
      pictureBox3.Visible = true;
      pictureBox3.Image = croppedBitmap;

      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      pictureBox3.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox3.Image.RawFormat);
      byte[] imgbyte = ms.ToArray();
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(surveyreportRef, (this.insertnote.Text), imgbyte); //
      surveyreportRef++;
      croppedBitmap.Dispose();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
}
```

Comment: @Equalsk Thanks for the reply but I don't understand why you say there is a duplicate how can I remove it?

Comment: Did you try what it said in the answer? You can't use `RawFormat` when saving an in memory bitmap, so specify a different format such as `Bmp`.

Comment: If I replace the 'RawFormat' with 'Bmp' or 'Bitmap' I get an wavy redline error similarly if I change it to 'PixelFormat'. Can you show me what the correct line of code should be?

Comment: I have tried to use

Comment: 'croppedBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);' but I now get the program stopping with an' Argument Exception was unhandled' message.

Comment: The code `croppedBitmap.Save(...)` is not in your question, and on what line does this new error occur?

Comment: I changed the line pictureBox3.Image Save(ms etc to croppedBitmap.Save( etc I was trying to use a defined Bitmap rather than a pictureBox3.Image. The error shows up in the Program.cs at' Application.Run(new Form1());'

Comment: I doubt the error occurs there, that's the entry point for your entire program. Given it's thrown by the try/catch shown in your question it must originate from there, read the stacktrace properly or edit the question to reflect the current details.

Comment: @Equalsk Many thanks for your help. I traced the error back and it works OK now... :)